# UITapGestureRecognizer w/multiple touches issue?

Tags: ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I'm wondering if anybody else has had problems with setting up a UITapGestureRecognizer with multiple touches (NOT multiple taps).  If I set the number of touches to 1 everything works pretty well.  If I set the number of touches to 2 the recognizer is triggered about 80% of the time.  If I set the number of touches to 3 then it's triggered about 10% of the time.  I'm attaching the recognizer to a UIWebView.  I've even tried messing around with delaysTouchesBegan/End to see if that helps things.  Anyone have any suggestions on how to make 2 and 3 touches work more reliably?

Comment: I've figured it out.  When I add the following delegate method:-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return( YES );
}
Everything starts working like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from the comment above:

> I've figured it out. When I add the following delegate method:

```
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return( YES );
}
```

> Everything starts working like a champ. – rforte 2 days ago